# Sortable list with mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to make a list sortable and make the order persist in mongodb. Each time the list is sorted, the frontend sends an array via ajax with the updated order of items by id, for example:

["some id #", "some other id #", etc]

I'm new to mongodb and not sure how to update the db accordingly. What I have so far in the post request:

```
Gallery.findById(req.params.galleryId, function(err, gallery) {
    req.body.ids.forEach(function(id, index) {
        gallery.Galleryslides.update({_id: id}, {sortIndex: index});
    });
    gallery.save(function() {
        res.json({status: 'ok'});
    });
});
```

Galleryslides is an array in the gallery schema that contains an array of the slides. When I run the abovee I get:

```
TypeError: gallery.Galleryslides.update is not a function
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned `Galleryslides` is an array so there is no `update` method for that.

So it should be like (if it's an array):

```
gallery.update({'Galleryslides._id': id}, {'$set': {'Galleryslides.$.sortIndex': index}});
```

If it's a embedded document :

```
gallery.Galleryslides.id(id).sortIndex = index;
```

If it's relationship :
Actually no need to go through parent model. Just update by `GallerySlide` model.

Please take a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

```
async.eachOf(req.body.ids, function(id, index, callback){
  GallerySlide.update({_id: id}, {sortIndex: index}, callback);
}, function(err){
  if(err) return res.json(err);
  res.json({status: 'ok'});
});
```

Comment: Hmm looks good, but doesn't change the order in the db for some reason

Comment: @BenDavidow Absoluteley it doesn't reorder in db. It just update array items. If you want to order in db is fine, you need to sort locally and set the whole array in db

Comment: okay but not sure why the db isn't changing. I use gallery.save

Comment: Sure, thanks: module.exports = mongoose.model('Gallery', {
    headline: String,
    slug: String,
    deck: String,
    author: String,
    tags: String,
    status: String,
    Galleryslides: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Galleryslide'}],
    slides: Array
});

Comment: @BenDavidow Oh it is not array. It's relation. So my answer does not work. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch, will test out

Comment: When I run this, I get "gallery.Galleryslides.id is not a function"

Comment: @BenDavidow My bad. So you need to populate `Galleryslides` and update them

Comment: @BenDavidow I updated my answer. It contains the right way